# Convert an Entity to a extended class based on original class?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Employee class which is an Entity Framework code first class representing an Employee. I would like to create a view model based on the original Employee class and then populate that class from a linq query to my EF context.

```
 public class EmployeeVM : Employee
{  
    public List<DepartmentSelect> Departments { get; set; }
}

EmployeeVM employee = context.Employees.Find(id);
```

I get the error "cannot implicitly convert type Employee to EmployeeVM."
Is there a simple way to do this rather then creating a new object and foreaching every parameter into the equivalent in the new class?

Comment: Befor doing anything read this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx. It's better to copy all your properties to your viewModel class because you have more contorl over them, for instance you can use data anotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

be nice if coding had an easy button, but it is what it is.. You could write the code one time and reuse it if you want.  You could use AutoMapper and deal with some of the headaches that come with that.  Your best bet would just be to write it yourself and maybe catch some errors if your context changes..

Without a mapper you could just add a static func to your viewmodel that will take an Employee object and create an EmployeeVM and use this in your context queries.

```
public class EmployeeVM
{
    public EmployeeVM()
    {
        Departments = new List<DepartmentSelect>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Dob { get; set; }

    public List<DepartmentSelect> Departments { get; set; }

    public static Func<Employee, EmployeeVM> FromEntity = item => new EmployeeVM() { 
        Id = item.Id,
        FirstName = item.FirstName,
        LastName = item.LastName,
        Dob = item.Dob
    };
}

// get single EmployeeVM
var eVm = EmployeeVM.FromEntity(context.Employees.Find(id));

// get List<EmployeeVM
var eVmList = context.Employees.Select(EmployeeVM.FromEntity).ToList();
```

This isnt recommended but if Employee is a partial class you could always just extend it by adding another partial class in the same namespace.

```
public partial class Employee
{
    //Add Extra Properties
    public List<DepartmentSelect> Departments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It isn't so much wanting to take the easy route but rather getting it all working only to discover that there was an easy route I didn't know about. ;)

Answer (score 0):

you maybe want to use Automapper. http://automapper.org/

Answer (score 0):

Tools like AutoMapper are designed to ease the burden of having a bunch of property-mapping code. You can also just serialize the first object and deserialize it into the second one.

I should probably mention, though, that this is probably a misuse of inheritance. Is there a reason you can't just put your Employee entity directly on your EmployeeVm as a property? Beyond that, Arash is right in pointing out that ViewModels should generally not be tightly coupled to your data model.